# How to delete my network profile description?

Tags: support, profile-page

I accidentally propagate my [TeX.SE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/) profile to all my StackExchange accounts.

I would like to undo this action, that is to say:

- delete my profile description on my (global) network profile.
- delete my profile description on all my StackExchange websites accounts *except* [TeX.SE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/).
- get back my original identicon which has been changed when I accidentally propagate my TeX.SE profile to all my SE accounts (is it possible?)

I only have a button "Sync with oldest profile (TeX - LaTeX)." but not the other way around...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll have to manually reinstate your old profile, I am afraid. Google cached some of your profiles; but the French.SE cached copy is the same as what you have on Tex.SE, the Stack Overflow profile is not cached and Academia.SE is cached with an empty About Me section.

Edit one profile, push it out to all other sites, then edit Tex again and *don't* hit that 'copy' button this time.

The avatar is a Gravatar, based on your email address; reinstate the same email address you had before and the same Gravatar image will be used.

Comment: Thanks. I changed indeed my email address (and it is the reason why my gravatar changed).